# How to create AI Images (Midjourney) by code?

Tags: discord, artificial-intelligence, stable-diffusion

I want to create an app that creates Midjourney images.

The problem is that Midjourney doesn't provide an API, it works from Discord.

How to automate the process of image generation without the need to open Discord?

Comment: You don't. The service currently isn't designed for such usage.

Comment: it should be, its would be more used

Comment: Good luck getting Midjourney working with Discord ... I wasted a day on this.

Discord is an auto-loaded pie in your face.

Win 10/64.

progra,mmer for > 25 years.

Bill

Comment: A reminder: Per Midjourneys TOS any kind of automation will get your account banned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use your own Midjourney account and host it as your own api-service, you could check out projects like Midjourney Proxy (https://github.com/novicezk/midjourney-proxy) on GitHub.

If you are looking for off-the-shelf service provider, you could check out goapi's [Midjourney API](https://www.goapi.ai/midjourney-api?utm_source=bl&utm_medium=so&utm_campaign=bl_so&utm_id=0913): [https://www.goapi.ai](https://www.goapi.ai/midjourney-api?utm_source=bl&utm_medium=so&utm_campaign=bl_so&utm_id=0913)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at <s>[thenextleg.io](https://thenextleg.io)</s> (closed service) [userapi.ai](https://userapi.ai), it has an API available for Midjourney there.

You will need a webhook URL to receive responses

Comment: A reminder: Per Midjourneys TOS any kind of automation will get your account banned.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this guide:

https://medium.com/@neonforge/how-to-create-a-discord-bot-to-download-midjourney-images-automatically-python-step-by-step-guide-3e76d3282871

Also read the comment regarding full automation- there a second post explaining how to do it using GUI automation:

> Discord API doesn’t allow sending commands by using bot. So if you are planning to send ‘/imagine” command by using Discord API you are out of luck. The only working way is a GUI automation. Check my recent article on this topic
> https://medium.com/@neonforge/how-to-automate-midjourney-image-generation-with-python-and-gui-automation-ac9ca5f747ae

Comment: Note that linked content is not considered part of an answer here. So if you don't think that "GUI automation" is a helpfully detailed answer you might want to [edit] and improve according to [answer]. That way you could also reduce the risk of being considered a self-promoter (and there are worse expression for that....). Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Answer (score 1):

You may do such for Image generation (DALL·E) by using OpenAI API. But it's not free at all
[Dall-e API](https://openai.com/blog/dall-e-api-now-available-in-public-beta)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the services for working with Midjourney via API. For example tnl (they have a very good community, but lately, of course, there have been a lot of complaints and account bans), on the downside, the service is paid for

You can use free services, the same [userapi.ai](https://userapi.ai)

In any case, you need to have a Discord account and a subscription in this account on Midjourney

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ttapi.io](https://ttapi.io), it has an availableMidjourney Api. also can use v6